# How much can a 1,00,000 visit site earn

Tags: google-adsense

I have an adsense account from years and my site gets 1,00,000 visits each month and earn 3,000$ a month. We get 100 to 200 clicks each day

I know that no-one can predict how much a site can earn, and it depends on a niche and 100's of things, but my question is can a site earn 3,000$ for every 1,00,000 visits? Is this heard before?
Just that i am not alone...

Comment: What is 1,00,000? did you mean 100,000 or 1,000,000?

Answer (score 2):

For every $1 your adsense account earns, somebody else is earning $10.

I can't begin to list all the ways you could make money from 100,000 visitors a month, and every site is different, but here are a few common techniques:

- Find out what kinds of adverts your visitors are buying from the click ads, and sell that product to them yourself.
- If your site is a blog, make a book of your "greatest hits" with special bonus content.
- Sell themed merchandise.
- Add sponsored content.